# Can't get comments to display correctly and comments not showing in moderation tool

Tags: comments, facebook-comments

I'm setting up Facebook comments on a WordPress blog. I have specific requirements so I can't use the Wordpres plugins for this.
Problem now is I can't get the FB comments to show comment count or to show the comments in the FB moderation dashboard.
Attached is how the comment box is coming out

I used this Facebook page for instructions setting the FB comments: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/

Created new app and have App ID. Have the 2 FB meta tags for App ID and Admin in the header. used the settings in the picture below. The first just under the  and the other in the comments.php file.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing too.  I've specified the app id and admin ids.  I've got a lot of comments in the plug in.  I'm loading the JS SDK using the ID in the query string.  I, as the admin, have also liked the page/website to ensure I've accepted my admin rights for that appid and link url.  I've had other users come in and "report" some comments (the same X as you'd use to delete your own comments, but on other people's comments).  I don't know what more to do to be able to moderate

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the first of my issues. To make the comment count (the noe that has a drop down option to sort comments) show, reduced the number of default number of posts (`data-num-posts="2"` from the 15 I had put to the default 2.

Still don't have anything in my moderation panel though